# Animating two figures with different data units using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to plot two separate animations, i.e. in different windows as separate figures. Running this code for me rightly creates two windows, but animates the data on the second figure at the same time. Closing figure 1 results in only the intended data for figure 2 being animated, removing the overlap from the data intended for figure 1. Closing figure 2 results in only the intended data for figure 1 being animated, removing the overlap from the data intended for figure 2.

Minimum code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

dx, dv, N, Nb, decp = 2, 1.5, 100, 12, int(1)
Pd = np.zeros([N + 1, 2 * Nb])
Vd = np.zeros([N + 1, 2 * Nb])

Pd[:, 1] = 4
Vd[:, 3] = 2

t = np.zeros(N + 1)
t[0] = 0
for i in range(0, N):
    t[i + 1] = (i + 1) * 0.1

Px = []
for i in range(0, (2 * Nb)):
       
    PX = dx * (-Nb + i) / 4
    Px.append(PX)


lblx = []
for i in range(0, int((Nb / 2) + 1)):
    if i == (Nb / 4):
        LBL = r"$\mu_x$"
        lblx.append(LBL)
    else:
        LBL = r"${0}\sigma_x$".format(-(Nb / 4) + i)
        lblx.append(LBL)


Pv = []
for i in range(0, (2 * Nb)):
       
    PV = dv * (-Nb + i) / 4
    Pv.append(PV)


lblv = []
for i in range(0, int((Nb / 2) + 1)):
    if i == (Nb / 4):
        LBL = r"$\mu_v$"
        lblv.append(LBL)
    else:
        LBL = r"${0}\sigma_v$".format(-(Nb / 4) + i)
        lblv.append(LBL)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
def animatex(i):
       
    fig1.clear()
    plt.bar(Px, Pd[i, :], width = dx / 4, align = 'edge', color = 'b', \
        label = 't = {} seconds'.format(round(t[i], decp)))
    s_ticks = np.arange(-3 * dx, (3 + 1) * dx, dx)
    plt.xticks(s_ticks, lblx)
    plt.ylim(0, np.max(Pd))
    plt.xlim(-3 * dx, 3 * dx)
    plt.legend()
    plt.draw()

anix = FuncAnimation(fig1, animatex, repeat = True, interval = 200, frames = N + 1)


fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
def animatev(i):
       
    fig2.clear()
    plt.bar(Pv, Vd[i, :], width = dv / 4, align = 'edge', color = 'b', \
        label = 't = {} seconds'.format(round(t[i], decp)))
    s_ticks = np.arange(-3 * dv, (3 + 1) * dv, dv)
    plt.xticks(s_ticks, lblv)
    plt.ylim(0, np.max(Vd))
    plt.xlim(-3 * dv, 3 * dv)
    plt.legend()
    plt.draw()

aniv = FuncAnimation(fig2, animatev, repeat = True, interval = 200, frames = N + 1)

plt.show()
```

As is probably clear, they are two bar plots, with different vertical and horizontal dimensions. I've seen some solutions for these kinds of problems where the data shares an axis through a shared variable, but here they are not (as can be seen).
For this minimum code, the solution involves having the two bars, one in Pd and the other in Vd, being on their respective intended figures, not both on the second figure.

Let me know if there are any issues with the information here i.e. minimal code requirements not met, more information etc. and I will update.

Ignore any wayward writing style, it is not relevant.

Comment: don't use `plt`.  Instead make an axes and use the methods on the axes: `fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(); fig2.clear(); ax2.bar(...) etc`

Comment: @JodyKlymak given this a go by just replacing all plt with axi, i=[1,2] and changed figi = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6)) to figi, axi = plt.subplots(). Then FuncAnimation gives the following error: "TypeError: draw_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'renderer'". Just putting "axi" as an argument in FuncAnimation didn't fix this. Apologies if I'm not seeing simplicity in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

dx, dv, N, Nb, decp = 2, 1.5, 10, 12, int(1)

Px = np.arange(Nb)
Pd = np.random.randn(N, Nb)
Vd = np.random.randn(N, Nb)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))


def animatex(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.bar(Px, Pd[i, :], width=dx / 4, align='edge', color='b')
anix = FuncAnimation(fig1, animatex, repeat=True, interval=200, frames=N)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))


def animatev(i):
    ax2.clear()
    ax2.bar(Px, Vd[i, :], width = dv / 4, align='edge', color='b')
aniv = FuncAnimation(fig2, animatev, repeat=True, interval=200, frames=N)

plt.show()
```

works fine for me.  You can add the esthetic/data details back in...

Comment: I clearly need to brush up on subplotting! Thanks very much for this, I appreciate your time.